# Weblogic EJB CMT: Transaction does not rollback

Tags: ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c

I am following the EJB standard for CMP as specified in the specification but it does not rollback changes in a database. When I have commented-out `Connection.close()` (`Connection` is retrieved from a Data-source) it is rollbacked successfully.

Is it recommended for WebLogic to not close a connection received from a data source?

Comment: I think you problem is not related to open/close connection. Try to post some code that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: I got solution , transaction not related to connection close/open , instead of related to DataSource>Transation>GlobalTransaction setting , But is weblogic reccommend not to close connection received from dataSource .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it recommended for WebLogic to not close a connection received from a data source?

There is a rule that when inside a container managed transaction you should never call any method that manually or natively interacts with a transaction on a transactional resource.

But `Connection.close()` is not such a method. Even though connections are managed, when you obtain one from an injected data source, you indeed have to close it. Note that this will in most cases not actually close the connection, but with a transaction in progress the transaction manager will most likely keep the connection on hold to be able to do the commit or rollback on it when the overall transaction commits resp. rollbacks.

Note that a connection can be closed automatically when using a try-with-resources construct. Otherwise you indeed have to call the `close()` method on it (wrapped in some amount of finally clauses).

This is a fairly standard pattern:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:app/dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void doStuff() {
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            // do work on connection
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

See this link for some more discussion on this topic: http://www.coderanch.com/t/485357/EJB-JEE/java/releasing-connection-CMT